# Forward traffic to port 80 on WHM via iptables

Tags: iptables

I'm working on a VPS (DV) that's hosted on Media Temple.  I need to forward traffic from port `8774` to `80`.  I logged in as root, ran

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8774 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80
```

and then `iptables-save`

When I show iptables rules I can see my rule...

```
# iptables -t nat -L -n -v --line-numbers
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 88 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8774 redir ports 80

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 5 packets, 300 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 5 packets, 300 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

When I access `myDomain.com:8774` I'm not able to see the same page I see when I access `myDomain.com`.

From what I'm reading on other resources these are the correct steps.

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: Chrome shows a generic error page and this at the bottom: `Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not including the network adapter and only checking the protocol.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8774 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80
```